# Is there a way to check if sound is audibly playing? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to develop a rythm game, whilst extremely new to unity(but my dad knows quite a bit, not this though) and it is going pretty well. I know that you can detect when audio is playing, when the pitch is going up and down, and when audio stops playing. What I need to know is when the player can hear audio, not just having it be true in the quiet bits. I'm sorry for not having code, frankly, I have no idea where to start.

Edit: it wont let me do the right tag, this is unity 2d.

Edit 2: I guess I should rephrase, it doesnt matter if the player actually hears it, more there is sound playing. Lets say theres a 2 minute song, and the song only starts 12 seconds in, how would I know, 12 seconds in, "oh, sound is playing!" not just knowing "oh, the song is playing" at 0 seconds.

Comment: i would presume your audio source has a max distance, you could just check the distance between audio source and player and see if it is inside max distance. everything else is super ambiguous, because you have no way of actually making sure the player hears it. Sound could be lowered from outside the game, player could have hearing impairment etc. etc.

Comment: Sorry, it was a bit wierd how I worded it @nka_Zz , I added an edit that clarifies it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for actual sound in the sound file you would need to check the Spectrum data of your AudioClip with [`AudioSource.GetSpectrumData()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.GetSpectrumData.html) and check if there are any peaks

so basically grab the spectrum data each frame could be something like that

```
float[] sample = new float[256];
_audioSource.GetSpectrumData(sample, 0, FFTWindow.Blackman)
```

after that you need to check the sample for values that are not 0. The length of the sample must be power 2 but you could take 128 as well, all depends on how accurate you want to be.

Comment: Alright sick, thanks man! That should be all I need, I'm making a rhythm game and don't wanna make maps cause it would be hard for how my game works, coolio.